# Commuting 3D Rotations Special Case?

Tags: 3d, rotations

I have a product of 3D rotations such as
$$\prod_{i=1}^{n}R_0R_i=R_0R_1R_0R_2R_0R_3\dots$$
Note that $R_0$ is constant. I would like to rearrange the product separating the $R_0$'s from the rest such that I can compute those separately. Something like
$$\prod_{i=1}^{n}R_0R_i=f(R_0,n)\cdot g(R_1, R_2, \dots)$$
Is this possible at all? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The group $SO(3)$ has free subgroups, so there is no identity that you can use here that isn't applicable in every group.

Comment: Does that mean that what I'm trying to do is not possible?

Comment: $R_0 R_1 R_0 R_2 R_0 \cdots R_0 R_n$ is a *sequence of rotations*, applied in order, from right to left. So no, OP's second form is not possible, because removing any $R_0$ from the sequence changes the effect of all the following rotations.

Comment: Robert, Nominal, thanks for the answers!